# How to change dynamic QLabel with a Pixmap (QList)

Tags: qt, qpixmap, qlabel, qlist

I have the following scenario: With an add Button I create a dynamic QLabel, and it gets a QPixmap, the first one is different then the other. So if I add a second one, everything is fine. The problem starts by adding a third. Then my second shown label should be replaced. I give you some picture that will explain my problem and my source code.
At first a picture of the current situation after 2 times add clicked:[image: 2times add]

and here after i clicked it the third time, as you can see the pixmap in the middle should be replaced by one without a crossbar:
[image]

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    counter=0;

    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Verteiler links

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{


    int xposition;
    QPixmap vert_links("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_links");
    QPixmap vert_mitte("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_mitte");
    QPixmap vert_rechts("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_rechts");

    QLabel *label = new QLabel ();
    //add Label to the List
    qlist.append(label);

    xposition=counter*60;

    if  (counter==0)
    {
        label->setPixmap(vert_links);
    }
    else
    {
        xposition=xposition+35;
        label->setPixmap(vert_rechts);
    }
    if (counter>1)
    {
        QLabel *label2 = new QLabel ();
        label2->setPixmap(vert_mitte);
        label2->show();
        label2->setParent(this);
        label2->setGeometry((xposition-60),500,125,172);
        qlist.replace(2,label2);

    }
    label->setParent(this);
    label->setGeometry((xposition),500,125,172);
    label->show();

    counter++;

}
```

I get following error from QT "setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 89x172+915+454 on 'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  116x172+915+454 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8)."
I guess it is, because i just change the value in my list and not the diplayed one, but i have no clue how to code it correctly.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where do you remove previous label? Why don't you use layouts? Why don't you create one label and change only picture on it? And why do you create two labels, when `counter>1`??

Comment: i am not removing the prev. label. This sound like a problem ;). I am not using layouts, because i have to positions my labels right next to each other, or can i do it with layouts? how to change the picture in it, when its dynamic? I create the second label to replace it with the on before

Comment: You can place widget right next to each other, by setting [layout spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) to zero. `setPixmap` changes picture, all you need to do is to make `QLabel` a member of `QMainWindow` class. And I still cannot understand, why do you need `label2` along with `label`. Also, if you need to unite several pictures in one, you can do it within `QPixmap` class, using `QPainter`, without creating several labels.

Comment: can you give me please a code snippet? I mean my actual Problem is, i dont know how to change the value of the previous created label. How to get to that label?

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{


    int xposition;
    QPixmap vert_links("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_links");
    QPixmap vert_mitte("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_mitte");
    QPixmap vert_rechts("C:/Users/Boushar/Desktop/Bachelor_Fred/Coden/Verteiler_rechts");

    QLabel *label = new QLabel ();
    //add Label to the List


    xposition=counter*60;

    if  (counter==0)
    {
        label->setPixmap(vert_links);
    }
    else
    {
        xposition=xposition+35;
        label->setPixmap(vert_rechts);
    }
    if (counter>1)
    {
     qlist.last()->setPixmap(vert_mitte);

    }
    qlist.append(label);
    label->setParent(this);
    label->setGeometry((xposition),500,125,172);
    label->show();

    counter++;

}
```

just changing my last listitem to the other pixmap, before adding the new one.
only question remaining is how to set the data from a specific list item. Like one before last

Comment: `if (qlist.count() > 1) qlist[qlist.size() - 2]->setPixmap(...);` ?

Comment: thanks man and sorry for that obvious question. i am quiete new to QT. i just know casual c++ lists ;)